# What is the possible solution if the asp.net hosting provider does not allow .exe files which I require for Roslyn Compiler?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, web-hosting, roslyn

I have developed a responsive asp.net website using Visual Studio 2015 Community  by choosing the default ASP.NET Forms template . On my local computer, the website runs perfectly fine, but when I uploaded all the files of the website to the internet server, I found that I am not able to upload three files with .exe extension namely "csc.exe","vbc.exe" and "VBCSCompiler.exe" under the path "/Bin/roslyn". I raised a ticket to my hosting provider net4india and they are saying that they don't allow .exe files to be uploaded on server as they may be potential viruses.  I had earlier developed this website on Visual Studio 2010 and was working perfectly fine on the hosting server also , but I wanted to make it responsive and I don't know how to use bootstrap, so I had choosen the template for ready-made coding, but now this is a big problem.  I have googled a lot on this issue, but not found anything even near to what I am facing , even on stackoverflow. How can I resolve this issue ? Is any work-around possible for this like converting the .exe to .dll files or anything like that ? Please help.

Comment: Why do you need the compiler? Can't you generate a deployment package and deploy it?

Comment: please refer some sources to learn how to host asp.net projects. links for windows hosting - http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis, for linx hosting - http://blog.tonysneed.com/2015/05/25/develop-and-deploy-asp-net-5-apps-on-linux/

Comment: @RubensFarias Earlier I had developed this website using Visual Studio 2010 and I was able to successfully deploy it on hosting server , but I developed it again using a sample asp.net forms template of Visual Studio 2015 Community to make my website responsive on mobile devices, but in doing so, I getting this issue.Can you guide me on how can I generate a deployment package and deploy it without the need of a compiler ?

Comment: @SiddhikaChhelavda: Either pick a better host, or switch to ASP.Net 4.5 and MVC 5.

Comment: @Slaks I have developed my website in .net framework 4.5.2 . is there any way to convert it to ASP.Net 4.5 and MVC 5 now ?

Answer (score 2):

You can deploy even without Roslyn with no change in code. Open NuGet Package Manager window and uninstall Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform package and rebuild & republish. This will solve your purpose. Basically this will not generate any csc.exe, vbc.exe files inside bin folder.

Answer (score 1):

No hosting provider will allow you to run exe files. If you really want that, you should go for (virtual) dedicated server.

Comment: Hi Rakesh, thanks for your reply. Is there any other work around for this without uploading .exe files ?

Comment: Many web hosts do allow EXEs.  You should pick a better host.