# Build with Roslyn, but leave the "compile-at-runtime" executables at the door?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, roslyn, c#-6.0, opserver

There has been a lot of talk about the C# compiler [Roslyn](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/c-60-in/9781491927090/ch27.html#whatapostrophes_new_in_chash_6dot0) on *StackOverflow* and the internet in general. A lot of people ask [what and why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33740123/what-why-is-roslyn-needed-in-bin-folder-of-asp-net) with Roslyn, while others ask how to [get rid of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282880/publish-website-without-roslyn).

My question pertains to the latter question. As quoted from *Kemal Kefeli* from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282880/publish-website-without-roslyn), but frequently iterated verbatim by dozens more (e.g. [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32648369/what-is-the-possible-solution-if-the-asp-net-hosting-provider-does-not-allow-ex?rq=1) of iteration), in order to remove Roslyn:

> When you create a new web project, two *NuGet* packages automatically added to your project. If you remove them, your problem should be solved. Package names are: "**Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform**" and "**Microsoft.Net.Compilers**".

This approach, however, does not work if you are using the C# 6 features that Roslyn offers. By removing these two nugget packages, you give up any chance of using these features.

My question is, how do you compiler everything with Roslyn, but avoid having any compiler-at-runtime actions occurring and most importantly, the `csc.exe`, `vbc.exe`, and `VBCSCompiler.exe` from being placed in the final release version (in the Roslyn folder).

I am porting over *StackOverflow's* **[Opserver](https://github.com/opserver/Opserver)** into a piece of software. The software allows users to host embedded web servers and web pages from within it. However, the software is very picky about what it allows to be uploaded and executables, like those found in the Roslyn folder, are **not** allowed to be uploaded and executed at runtime due to security reasons.

**[Opserver](https://github.com/opserver/Opserver)** relies on C# 6 features, because if I remove those two *NuGet* packages, errors sprout up in compile-generated files. But, if I more simply revert to [compile strictly with](https://www.codeproject.com/tips/865579/how-to-change-targeted-csharp-version-in-visual-st) the C#5.0 compiler, then we see this clearly:

[image: 5.0 errors## Heading ##]

If I leave the *NuGet* packages present and uncheck `allow precompiled site to be updatable` when publishing, in order to disallow Roslyn with compiling files at runtime as followed by *Rutix*'s comment from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282880/publish-website-without-roslyn):

> Keep in mind that removing these packages [as told by *Kemal Kefeli*] will break the use of C# 6 features. This could be solved by unchecking "Allow precompiled site to be updatable" which pre-compiles the views ect.

[image: Don't compiler at runtime]

It still generates the executables and the associated DLLs in the Roslyn folder, however significantly less DLLs. How can I possibly remove the Roslyn dependency at runtime and therefore the executables from the outputted version and strictly compile **everything** at compile-time?

Comment: I'm in the same boat as you are.

Comment: @HamzaAhmedZia I found a work around. When I have a moment in the next day or so, I will post an answer to my question.

Comment: @DanHoynoski Almost a year later, I'm trying to do exactly the same. Did that workaround solve your problem? can you post it?

Answer (score 3):

In fully precompiled ASP.NET project ("allow precompiled site to be updatable" disabled) there is no need for compiler to be deployed with app IMHO.

I'm using Roslyn in my .NET 4.6 ASP.NET app (mix of Web Forms and MVC) and precompiled app works just fine after removing Roslyn folder\files from published site...

**UPDATE**: After a while a found only place where absence of Roslyn in deployment package is the problem a that's accessing ASMX (old style ASP.NET SOAP web service) in browser - "help" page for ASMX is apparently build at runtime even for fully precompiled ASP.NET application and it throws exception (although WS itself runs OK)